# In MSFT SQL Server Management Studio, how do I morph an (excel) list into a query-able delimited list?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, delimiter, sql-server-2016

Using SQL Server 2016, I'd like to take a list from an (Excel) table such as

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

and transform it into something more usable, such as

```
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'
```

so that I can easily create conditionals such as

```
where type_code in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
```

How might this be done? I had the ability to do this in Aqua Data Studio's "Morph to Delimited List", but I'm unable to find a similar function in MSFT SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @delimiter  varchar(10)     = ','
       ,@qualifier  varchar(10)     = ''''
       ,@str        varchar(max)    =
'A
B
C
D
E'


select 
    @qualifier+replace(@str,char(13)+char(10),@qualifier+@delimiter+@qualifier)+@qualifier
```

> 'A','B','C','D','E'

---

```
declare @delimiter  varchar(10)     = '-'
       ,@qualifier  varchar(10)     = ''
       ,@str        varchar(max)    =
'A
B
C
D
E'

select 
    @qualifier+replace(@str,char(13)+char(10),@qualifier+@delimiter+@qualifier)+@qualifier
```

> A-B-C-D-E

Comment: This works, but ideally I'd like something a bit more robust - the ability to set an initial delimiter, resulting delimiter, and toggle quotes.  Is this something not available in SQL server?

Comment: See update, do the same for qualifiers, I'm off for the night.